# JSON.Net mapping circular references when deserializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a data structure which looks something like this: foo 1:* bar, e.g.

```
{
    id: 1,
    children: [
        { id: 1, fooId: 1, foo: null },
        { id: 2, fooId: 1, foo: null }
    ]
}
```

When deserializing this data structure, is there any way to make `JSON.Net` set the actual object references based on the keys (i.e. setting the `foo` property to the parent object in my example above)?

To elaborate further, this is what I'm after:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
Assert.AreEqual(data, data.children[0].Foo)
```

Comment: Have you defined the properties correctly in the `Foo` class? What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: And foo has child and go on forever. When does it finish? Why dont you make children refer to it's parent via foo Id?

Comment: Json.NET has a mechanism to preserve references, but it has a different syntax, see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm.  You might be able to add the back references inside an `[OnDeserialized]` callback, see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm

Comment: @DanNguyen The structure is about five levels deep. Yeah I want them to reference the parent just as they do today. But I want JSON.Net to map the actual parent object reference too, if possible.

Comment: @Jerodev There is no problem, I'm asking about a deserialization feature. Sorry if that's unclear

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I'll look in to that

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking to define a specific set of structures to deserialize into..**

I have used this (and similar utilities) to get going and then modified as needed:
http://json2csharp.com

There is also a link to quicktype which offers additional features.

I have used the following utility as well which you just download and build, it's bare bones but did the job:

https://github.com/JsonCSharpClassGenerator/JsonCSharpClassGenerator/